# Redireccionamiento carga contenido html

Tags: href

Tengo un sistema donde cargo un codigo de barras, y al hacer click en un boton quiero redirigir a la cuenta corriente del cliente con dicho codigo:

```
   $("#ccg").click(function(){

    location.href="index.php?controller=cliente&action=deuda&id="+idg;
   });
```

Pero me carga contenido html sino me equivoco:
index.php?1=1&canillas1=1&promo1=0&2=1&canillas2=1&promo2=0&3=1&canillas3=1&promo3=0&4=1&canillas4=1&promo4=0&5=1&canillas5=1&promo5=0

ese es el resultado en la barra de direcciones del navegador.
Este es el html del boton:

```
   <div class="col-sm-2">
 <button id="ccg" class="btn btn-primary"> <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon- 
 list"> IR A CC</span></button>
   </div>
```

Que puede ser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mejor usa la notación completa

```
window.location.href= "index.php?controller=cliente&action=deuda&id="+idg;
```

Ya que location.href, segun la documentación es solo lectura.

Comment: Gracias por comentar..Acabo de probar y no funciona, sigue igual

Comment: Si hago un alert me muestra bien la direccion con el idg.. No entiendo porque el problema

Comment: Hola cuando hagas la peticion fijate si la peticion se hace bien, en la parte network en las herramientas de desarrollador. Para entrar ahi en google chrome es la tecla F12.

Comment: Si gracias.. De hecho hice un log del resultado y me muestra bien el array del cliente en cuestion. Tambien hice un alert de idg y contiene el id.